# What is the main cause of box-shadow not to work

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I have to been trying to search for a solution to my problem that is my box-shadow not working, I have seen other question on Stack Overflow that are similar but the all did not solve my problem can I please get some help

**Code below is my React Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "../StyleSheet/MainDashBaordWindow.css";
const HomeDashContent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="DashBoardContent">
      <h1 className="DashBoardContent__header">Welcome Back!</h1>
      <div className="DashBoarContent__mainWindow">
        <div className="mainWindow__cards left-card">
          <h2>On Going Shipments</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mainWindow__cards right-card">
          <h2>Finished Shipments</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeDashContent;
```

**Code below is my stylesheet**

```
.DashBoardContent {
  flex: 0.8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.DashBoardContent__header {
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.DashBoarContent__mainWindow {
  display: flex;
}

.mainWindow__cards {
  background-color: #f5f5f5f5;
  padding: 4em 2em;
  height: 30vh;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 2rem 2.5rem 2rem solid lightslategray;
}

.mainWindow__cards:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.left-card {
  margin-right: 5em;
}

.right-card {
  margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Comment: Same as any other property not working. The value is invalid.

Comment: I do not think I understand what value is invalid?

Comment: `solid` is an invalid value in `box-shadow` property.

Comment: try using `box-shadow: 2rem 2.5rem 2rem lightslategray;`

Comment: You should read the box shadow specification "solid" is not allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Thanks I will give it a read, just out of curiosity I write my box shadows like this always and sometimes it works and sometimes does it like today. So what cause it to work sometime with **solid** included?

Comment: Change box shadow for border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Solid' value is not available for the box-shadow property. Just try to put a length value like 1px for the spread value(which is the fourth property value for box-shadow) instead of solid and it's gonna work.